# Setting section and subsection font with titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I am trying to set [Roboto](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue//roboto/) as the section font and [Roboto Condensed](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue//robotocondensed/) as the subsection font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{roboto}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\roboto\color{blue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}   {\normalfont\large\bfseries\robotocondensed\color{blue}}

\begin{document}  
\section{This title should be Roboto}    
\subsection{This subtitle should be Roboto Condensed}    
Text text text
\end{document}
```

However, the command `\robotocondensed` is not working:

[image: error image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You can get the expected result with `xelatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pdfLaTeX, command `\robotocondensed` is defined as

```
\newcommand*\robotocondensed{\fontseries{c}\selectfont}
```

So it only changes the font series. Because of this your setting of the `\subsection` font still uses Computer Modern and tries to load an not provides font series, which results in the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bc/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 11.
```

To get Roboto bold condensed, you have to use `\roboto\robotoboldcondensed`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{roboto}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\roboto\color{blue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}   {\normalfont\large\roboto\robotoboldcondensed\color{blue}}

\begin{document}  
\section{This title should be Roboto}    
\subsection{This subtitle should be Roboto Condensed}    
Text text text
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

independent from using pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much!